# Binary Search is not returning 0 if no element is matched

Tags: c++, binary-search

I Wrote a program for binary search using cpp. Its working fine except if the Searched Element is not found in the Vector, its returning Garbage value while it should be returning 0.

Here's the code -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int BinarySearch(vector<int> v,int x,int y,int t){
    if(x>y){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        int m=x+(y-x)/2;
        if(v[m]==t)
        return m;
        else if(v[m]>t){
            BinarySearch(v,x,m-1,t);
        }
        else
        BinarySearch(v,m+1,y,t);
    }
}
main(){
    int n,m=0,no;
    vector <int> v;
    cout<<"Enter the No of Elements u wanna store in the Array : ";
    cin>>n;
    while(n--){
        cout<<"Enter Element "<<++m<<" : ";
        int t;
        cin>>t;
        v.push_back(t);
    }
    cout<<"Enter the no u wanna search for : ";
    cin>>no;
    int Start=0,End=v.size()-1;
    int B=BinarySearch(v,Start,End,no);
    if(B==0){
        cout<<"Element not Found\n";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"The Element is : Element "<<B+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it ever make sense to call `BinarySearch` and ignore the value returned from it?

Comment: Also, programming wil become much easier once you [enable compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/8bdGM9saK).

Comment: Don't rely on us guessing input where this fails if you already know about one such input and could entirely remove reading from stdin using hardcoded values instead. How do you intend to tell cases where the first element contains the searched element appart from cases where the element is not found?

Comment: Note `vector<int> v` is passed by value, not reference, and that's going to get expensive. I recommend passing it as `const vector<int> & v` instead.

Comment: *Its working fine except* -- It isn't working fine.  Also [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) does what your `BinarySearch` function is trying to do.

Comment: Also, a binary search requires the items to be sorted.  Where do you guarantee that the items are sorted?

Comment: There are paths through `BinarySearch` where no value is returned.  Also in `BinarySearch`, you need to assign the return value to a variable and return the variable.

Comment: Important:  Is your `BinarySearch` to return the value if found or is it to return `true` or `false`?  If the latter, the return type should be `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in the section

```
if(B==0){
        cout<<"Element not Found\n";
    }
```

as if an element is found at index 0 then its going to print element not found.

You can use this as a solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int BinarySearch(std::vector<int> vec, int start, int end, int num)
{
    if (start >= 1)
    {

        int mid = 1 + (end - start) / 2;
        if (vec[mid] == num)
            return mid;
        if (vec[mid] > num)
        {
            return BinarySearch(vec, start, mid - 1, num);
        }

        return BinarySearch(vec, mid + 1, end, num);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

this line:

```
int m=x+(y-x)/2;
```

is flawed as x is going to be 0 except in the case of the recursive call `BinarySearch(v,m+1,y,t);` as well as the fact that you're just calling it and not returning the value of the function call

Essentially, the answer to your question is that it is returning a garbage value instead of 0 because the condition of the outer if statement in your BinarySearch function is not being met and having no other return statement in your function being the reason.

P.s. having meaningful parameter/variable names is important practice especially when having others read your code

Answer (score 0):

1. You are just calling `BinarySearch` function again without returning its value
2. Returning `0` is wrong because you will not know whether it exists at `0` or not found
3. You should sort the vector: `#include<algorithm>` then `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`
4. Write `int main()` or `void main()` not `main()` because the third does not work on all compilers
5. Pass `std::vector` by const reference `const std::vector& v` in the function
6. Better not `using namespace std`
7. I think `m = (x + y)/2` looks more elegant

Comment: 4) It should always be `int main()`.  As to 7), the `(x + y)` can overflow, so elegance goes out the window.